# Special characters in a srping boot application error when launched from cmd and from STS

Tags: spring-boot, cmd, encoding, special-characters, spring-tool-suite

I am developing a Vaadin Spring Boot application.
When I start the app from the Spring Tool Suite everything is ok.
But when I start it from cmd, I get errors on special characters like german umlauts.

Started from cmd: JÃ¼rgen HÃ¶ller

Started from STS: Jürgen Höller

Any ideas? It must run as a service, so I need to run it from a bat in cmd.
I am working with a german edition of windows 10 in Germany

Comment: Please *do not* use images of code (nor result data) in your [mcve]. Copy the actual text, paste it into the question, then format it as code. Post a hexadecimal dump in case of (partially) binary content. BTW, you face a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case (*example in Python for its universal intelligibility*): `'Jürgen Höller'.encode( 'utf-8').decode( 'latin1')` returns `'JÃ¼rgen HÃ¶ller'`

Answer (score 0):

It is a mojibake!

The problematic code was:

```
try (Reader reader = new FileReader(file)) {
```

The solution for it is:

```
try (Reader reader = new FileReader(file, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
```

Thanks JosefZ for pointing this out in your comment.